# How to have autocomplete ignore multiples?

Tags: coldfusion, autocomplete

Hello I have autocomplete set up like this:

index.cfm

```
<!--- A simple form for auto suggest --->
<cfform action="autosuggest.cfm" method="post">
    Park Name:<br />
    <cfinput type="text" name="parkname" size="50" autosuggest="cfc:autosuggest.findPark({cfautosuggestvalue})" autosuggestminlength="1" maxresultsdisplayed="10" /><br /><br />
</cfform>
```

and autosuggest.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <!--- Lookup used for auto suggest --->
    <cffunction name="findPark" access="remote" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="search" type="any" required="false" default="">

        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var local = {} />

        <!--- Query Location Table --->
        <cfquery name="local.query" datasource="#application.datasource#" >
            select      FirstName
            from        Users
            where       FirstName like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ucase(arguments.search)#%" />
            order by    FirstName
        </cfquery>

        <!--- And return it as a List --->
        <cfreturn valueList(local.query.FirstName)>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

What I need it to do is ignore multiples. Instead of having this: Dave, Jack, Jack, Jack, Chet. It should only do this: Dave, Jack, Chet. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` in your query instead of `SELECT`.

Comment: @SOfanatic - You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in your query.

```
<cfquery name="local.query" datasource="#application.datasource#" >
select      DISTINCT FirstName
from        Users
where       FirstName like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ucase(arguments.search)#%" />
order by    FirstName
</cfquery>
```